# Add product list in cart in Android app

Tags: android

How to add products in cart in my Android app? Which way do I need to implement it, should I use SQLite or ArrayList or Shared Preferences or some other way?

Comment: Shared preferences will be the good option!

Comment: @yogesh agrawal you tell me which vehicle should i  use to win a death race?  car van truck?

Answer (score 1):

Shared Preference is not good option to use.

To maintain the data added in cart by the user till transaction completes, you can use

```
ArrayList<ModelClass>
```

To maintain the history of cart, you can use

```
SQLite D.B
```

Below are some good post which can help you in achieving what you want.

```
http://androidexample.com/Use_MVC_Pattern_To_Create_Very_Basic_Shopping_Cart__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=116

http://www.androiddom.com/2011/02/android-shopping-cart-tutorial.html

http://www.uandblog.com/How-to-Create-a-Shopping-Cart-Application-in-Android
```

Hope this helps you.